# AVAudioSession did not activate after a GSM call is ended, while having a VoIP call ongoing

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, pjsip, callkit

I start a voip call from user A to user B using call kit, sound is routed correctly. I receive a native (GSM) call on user A. The user A choose "Hold & Answer" option, so the voip call will set on Hold while the GSM call will be routed correctly. 
At some point of time the GSM call is ended by the other party so I will end up having the voip call ongoing which is on hold at this time. 
When the GSM call is ended also the "didDeactivateAudioSession" is called. 
When I unhold the voip call I made the next actions:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
// unhold call
pjsua_call_reinvite([self identifier], PJ_TRUE, NULL);
```

Reinvite is working and properly unhold, but the AVAudiosession is not activate even if I call "setCategory:".

I had also try to activate audio session before or after setting the AVAudioSession category.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];
```

But activate audio session allways fails with next error:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "(null)"

I think there is the problem, but I had no ideea how to properly activate audio session.

Comment: did you add [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil]; before set category?

Comment: Yes I had tryed also with setActive before setting the category, but I encountred the same issue.

Comment: as I remember PJSUA hold and onhold the transaction by its own and dont need to use avaudioseesion

Comment: this will hold the transaction   pjsua_set_no_snd_dev();
            pjsua_call_set_hold(ID , NULL);

Comment: for unhold try this code  pjsua_set_snd_dev(captureDev, playbackDev);
        pjsua_call_reinvite(ID, PJ_TRUE, NULL);

Comment: I had tried to call pjsua_set_snd_dev(captureDev, playnackDev) at unhold action but I receive the next error: Unable to open sound device: Unknown error -560577449 [status=-560577449]

Comment: @engmahsa I had look deeper into this issue nad I find out that setActivate:YES method allways return error.

Comment: what happens if you keep calling `setActive` after the GSM call ends? and what's the error? p.s. why `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`?

Comment: I allways call setActivate after GSM call ends. That option has no relevance in this issue, I had try multiple aproaches but every thing end up in the same error.

Comment: Hi! I have same problem. did you find solution?

Comment: Hi is there any solution to the above problem, I am also not able to activate the audio session after a gsm call in ios 14.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find any solution till now.